# How to set ODBC connection in MapBasic

Tags: mapinfo, mapbasic

i am trying to set code for ODBC connection in Mapbasic. Instead of using Username and password i wanted to set code for Window authentication.my sample code is

```
Register table "tablename"
Type ODBC
Table "Select * From Database.tablename"
CONNECTION
"DSN=Database; UID=Username; PWD=Password"
into "C:\temp.table.tab"
```

so in this case instead of UID and PWD i wanted to set as window authentication to connect to database...anybody knows this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use "trusted_connection" attribute in your connection string. Set it to 'Yes'

```
Register table "tablename"
Type ODBC
Table "Select * From Database.tablename"
CONNECTION
"DSN=Database;Trusted_Connection=Yes"
into "C:\temp.table.tab"
```

---

**Trusted_Connection:** Trusted_Connection={yes | no}.

Determines what information the SQL Server Wire Protocol driver will use for login validation.

**When set to yes, the SQL Server Wire Protocol driver uses Windows NT Authentication Mode for login validation. *The UID and PWD keywords are optional*.**

When set to no, the SQL Server Wire Protocol driver uses a SQL Server username and password for login validation. The UID and PWD keywords must be specified.

Comment: Thnks...it works...